# Adding custom fields on asp net membership users table

Tags: asp.net

I have a application which I would like to add custom fields to the users table. I am not sure how to work after adding the columns. The columns are foreign keys to another table which holds more details for the user.

I am using Linq-to-SQL. So every time I add a user (using the membership functions i.e. `Membership.CreateUser(..)`) I end up calling another service to update the foreign keys on the users table.

Any better way of doing this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you adding foreign keys to the `User` table, pointing to another table with additional info??

I would do it the other way around:

- create your own table `UserInfo`
- create a FK column in `UserInfo` that points to the row in your ASP.NET membership `User` table
- leave the system-provided `User` table alone - so you won't run into problems when e.g. an upgrade to the ASP.NET membership system is rolled out.....

Comment: This is one to one relationship, if i go your way will mean the user can have more than one record?

Comment: @user1010863: theoretically - yes. You would have to check this in your app to make sure you don't have more than one entry at any given time

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you not to extend secure tables such like Users, Membership, Profile. Better create another one table in your database (not secure database) with full info which you need. Call it 'User' with foreign key to 'Id' of table User in secure database.